# How to increase stack size for unmanaged unit test in Visual Studio (2015)? Exception code: C00000FD

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, stack-size

I am trying to create a Unit Test project in VS2015. The project is built correctly and run until I try to create a local variable of large structure.

My code looks like:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace testTxRxTest11ac
{
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            largeStructure largeStruct;
            Assert::IsFalse(false);
        }

    };
}
```

When I remove largeStructure definition, the test passes. When I add largeStructure definition it fails with Exception Code: C00000FD. I googled this code and found that it is Stack overflow.

I tried to increase stack size in test project properies (Properties -> Linker -> System -> Stack Reserve Size).

I also tried to add #pragma comment(linker, "/STACK:10000000") in the test code and in the stdafx.cpp. Nothing worked.

Do you have any other suggestion how to deal with this error?

Comment: Have you tried with `/F stack_size_in_bytes`? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx) Having large objects on the stack is bad though, consider restructuring your code.

Comment: Please show the definition of `largeStructure`.

Comment: Your unit test runs with a stack that was allocated by the unit test runner.  You'd have to RTFM, but pretty doubtful that it has a test configuration setting to make it larger.  I don't recollect seeing such a setting.  Workaround therefore must be for the test code to use CreateThread() so the code can run with a larger stack.  But writing a test-failed bug report is certainly best.

Comment: @MarcoA. I do not understand where to write this line, even after reading the article. Could you help on this? And thanks a lot for suggestion on restructuring the code. Now I just use new to allocate the structure and it works well. But I am not sure if it is bad or not to allocate large objects on the stack. RAII is based on allocating everything on the stack as far as I understand it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Do not want to share the actual production code. The structure is a bunch of large multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @Nikita I doubt that posting a structure will disclose any trade secrets, anyway you could remove comments and obfuscate variable names. But anyway Hans Passant's comment is probably relevant to you.

Comment: @HansPassant I even have not found any documentation on this. Believe me I googled very hard and asked few experts before going here. Thanks for the suggestion on workaround.

Comment: @Nikita Nope, it is true that objects on the stack are automatically destroyed when the scope terminates but for large objects you either do the deallocation manually or even better use a smart pointer (so you get the best of both worlds). The `/F` option needs to be set in the property pages of your project -> C/C++ -> Command Line page -> Additional Options edit box.

Comment: @MarcoA. /F in the Additional Options does not help. The test project actually is built into a dll which than is called from VS test framework, so this option does not effect the stack size. Thanks for good tip about large objects.

Answer (score 1):

While this does not answer your original question, another approach would be to avoid using the stack altogether with your large class. Simply use the heap, which would make the testrunner stack space irrevelant. You could use a std::unique_ptr if you want to keep the same RAII semantics as you would have with your stack-based approach.